# Inherent TextView Padding

Tags: android, textview, padding

Does a `TextView` have some padding set by default? I'm trying to create two `TextViews` and I noticed that there's some padding in the `TextViews` without me explicitly setting it. If yes, then what's the value of it? Or where can I find more information on this?

Comment: I'm unsure how this Q has been downvoted. Have you found out anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there exists font padding in android.
you could aswell disable it by

```
mTextView.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

or xml attribute

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Is there any way of knowing the exact value of the font padding ?

Comment: Depends on the default font used in that particular device.